# Merging Rasters within Geodatabase using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have a geodatabase containing multiple rasters across the same extent with values of either null or 1. The goal is to merge these so where values of 1 overlap, the cell values are aggregated. Exactly the same as '+' in the Raster calculator tool.

This has worked using 'Mosaic to New Raster' however each raster dataset must be input separately into the model. I want to input all the data into the tool from one location.

Using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2

Comment: Have a look at the cell statistics tool in toolbox

Comment: I'd like to run this as part of a wider model so I'd like the selection of the rasters within the geodatabase to be automatic. Cell Statistics requires manual input I believe?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the rasters in the geodatabase (recursive turned on) to the Collect Values tool. The output of this can then be input into Mosaic To New Raster[image]

Comment: Your iterator feeding into the collects tool, they need to be in a sub-model. Your current design whilst "works" is highly inefficient. Search Help or this site for sub-models.